# Error 3706 Microsoft Visual Basic

Tags: banco-de-dados, vba, microsoft-access

Estou a fazer uma aplicação e quando fui programar o código do VBA para conectar com Banco de Dados do Access qual foi o meu espanto deu o erro:

> "Error 3706 Microsoft Visual Basic"

A linha de conexão é:

```
.ConnectionString = "Data Source=" & ThisWorkbook.Path & "\BD_Loja1.accdb"
```

Alguém pode me ajudar como resolver este erro?

Comment: Poste a linha completa da sua `ConnectionString`.

Comment: https://www.connectionstrings.com/access/

Answer (score 0):

Provavelmente é algum problema com seu `Provider`... Dê mais (muito mais) informações sobre o código sempre que for postar algo no stack pra que ajude a gente a te ajudar.

Pesquise qual o `Provider` deve ser usado com o tipo de banco e versão do access que você está usando. Abaixo segue um exemplo e sugestão de modificação do código (lembrando que você deve pesquisar o provider ideal para o seu caso e adicionar essa referência ao projeto)

```
strProvider = "Provider= Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.3.51;"
strDataSource = ThisWorkbook.Path
strDataBaseName = "\BD_Loja1.accdb;"
```